# sed convert 4 spaces to 2

Tags: sed

How does one convert 4 spaces into 2 spaces with `sed`? Is it possible?

I found this but it converts tab to spaces:

`sed -r ':f; s|^(\t*)\s{4}|\1\t|g; t f' file`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The script you posted converts 4*n spaces to n tabs, only if those spaces are preceded only by tabs.

If you want to replace 4 spaces by 2 spaces, but only in indentation, while it's possible to do it with sed, I recommend Perl instead.

```
perl -pe 's{^((?: {4})*)}{" " x (2*length($1)/4)}e' file
```

In sed:

```
sed -e 's/^/~/' -e ': r' -e 's/^\( *\)~    /\1  ~/' -e 't r' -e 's/~//' file
```

You may want to use [`indent`](http://www.gnu.org/software/indent/manual/indent.html) instead.

Comment: I got `Nested quantifiers in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/^( {4}* <-- HERE )/ at -e line 1.`

Comment: @eddygeek Oh, indeed, that and a few other bugs. I replaced the gobbledygook by actual perl code.

Answer (score 6):

Doesn't the straightforward way work:

```
sed -r 's/ {4}/  /g'
```

If not, post some input where it fails.

Comment: This is not resticted to the beginning of the line. If you anchor it there, it will not work for multiple matches. So we're at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/375200/259620 below.

Comment: This doesn't work if you have a combination of 2 spaces and 4 spaces, because two indentations of two will be counted as four...

Comment: @aexl: That was not a requirement by the OP

Comment: @mattfletcher: the question was about replacing 4 spaces with 2, so I fail to see your point

Answer (score 4):

If only leading spaces are to be converted:

```
sed 'h;s/[^ ].*//;s/    /  /g;G;s/\n *//'
```

With comments:

```
sed '
  h; # save a copy of the pattern space (filled with the current line)
     # onto the hold space
  s/[^ ].*//; # remove everything starting with the first non-space
              # from the pattern space. That leaves the leading space
              # characters
  s/    /  /g; # substitute every sequence of 4 spaces with 2.
  G; # append a newline and the hold space (the saved original line) to
     # the pattern space.
  s/\n *//; # remove that newline and the indentation of the original
            # line that follows it'
```

Also look at vim's `'ts'` setting and `:retab` command

Comment: Using your vim solution, is there a way to batch edit several files like that with vim? Otherwise i'm guessing i would have to create a macro?

Comment: Note that `'ts'` and `:retab` are not solutions to the question, but are related and may help address your overall goal. You can do `vim -- *.c`, `:set ts=...` and then `:argdo retab` or `:argdo retab!`. See also the `'sw'` option and vim's own indenting capabilities.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed 's/^\( \+\)\1\1\1/\1\1/' file
```

It works by dividing the leading spaces into four instances of the same group (so they're all equal) and then replacing them with only two instances of the group.

Comment: How does this improve the existing solutions?

Comment: It preserves odd spaces, only affects leading whitespace, doesn't require the global flag, can be easily tweaked to handle any number of spaces (or tabs) on both sides of the replacement and doesn't make use of more complex sed commands that can be off-putting for more casual users. As with many things, whether it's an improvement is pretty subjective, but speaking for myself: finding this in a script would be significantly easier to quickly grok than some of the other solutions listed.

Comment: Interesting. Glad I did ask. Usually backreferences are considered evil rather than the global flag. But you could easily achieve the same thing with more portable script (avoiding `\+`). Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/    \{2,4\}\( \{0,1\}[^ ].*\)*/  \1/g' <input
```

That should only squeeze leading sequences of spaces.